# Implementation of admob ads into a Cordova Javascript App

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

I recently signed up for an admob account in order to monetize my android app built using visual studio cordova(Javascript), but I was unable to get an sdk for javascript, I've surfed through the Internet but I couldn't find any help all the help am getting are for java(android and eclipse),but I stumbled upon this [Click to view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/admob) which I was unable get it working and also this [Click to view](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements) which is for phonegap/java and some other plugins from npmjs which I couldn't implement(the steps were a little bit confusing for me) . Please if there any simpler implementation can you quide me through or point me to a source or sources(websites/video) I don't mind.

Comment: Here is the list of the plugins [Click to View here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=admob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com-admob-plugin).
I have tried it and it is working perfectly.

And here is how to use it:

```
admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID","admob interstitial ID");
var admobParam = new admob.Params();
admobParam.isTesting = false;
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.SMART_BANNER, admob.Position.TOP_APP, admobParam);
```

Comment: Thanks,  please is there a tutorial video on how to do this.

Comment: The plugin is well documented and following the instructions was enough. But you can make use of [these examples](https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova/tree/master/Example)

Comment: Sorry, please how do you test (device or Ripple)? because am trying to test it on my phone and also ripple the ads is not showing up. (Note: Debug)

Comment: I tested it on a device and that was the code I used for implementation:

`admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID","admob interstitial ID");
var admobParam = new  admob.Params();
admobParam.isTesting = false;
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.SMART_BANNER, admob.Position.TOP_APP, admobParam);`

P.S. The IDs are generated from [google admob site](https://www.google.com.eg/admob/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

To add the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

To use it:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"  // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```